# Any way to learn where passwords are actually reused in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: passwords, microsoft-edge, password-management, windows-11-v22h2

A cool (?) feature of password health in *Microsoft Edge* → *Profiles*
→ *Passwords* tells me that my password is reused somewhere else:

[image]

I am surprised quite very much, because this particular password for this particular service was generated by a strong password generator embed in Microsoft Edge. So, per my knowledge, chances that it  is actually reused are minimal.

Is there any way to learn which password manager's item has the same password? Or do I have to browse through each and every item, manually reveal each password and see for this particular string of characters?

(Searching for password is not working in Microsoft Edge; you can only search for: a name, an URL and a login)

Answer (score 0):

I was way too fast in asking. Finding a duplicated password seems quite easy:

1. Go to Microsoft Edge → *Settings* → *Profiles* → *Passwords* (`edge://settings/passwords`)
2. Find item with reused password, reveal it and copy it to clipboard
3. (three dots) → *Export Passwords* → *Export Passwords* (confirm clicking blue button)
4. (scan finger print) / (provide PIN) / (dance in the rain) / (do whatever is needed)
5. Safe .csv file on the disk
6. Open it in Microsoft Excel or any other program that you use that can handle .csv files
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> / <kbd>Enter</kbd> (a few times).

You're done.

(after that) Recycle saved .csv files, purge Bin, restart computer (to purge memory) -- as it contains your whole digital life and you don't want a nasty guy/girl/person to take his/her/its hand on it, right?